# Whats the best and simple way to use SQLite with Delphi 10.3 Community Edition?

Tags: sqlite, delphi

I just started working with Delphi and I would like to develop an application that connects to a SQLite database. I see that there are many Data Components (dbEpress, Firedac, etc) and I am not sure which one, as a beginner, I should use. Basically, I want to use the Data Controls to display, include, edit, delete and also browse the table using the TBNavigator with TBGrid. As I am aware that SQLite is unidirecional, I would like to make sure I can go forward and backwards if I need to. I have heard something about buffering the query results so I can work on the data freely and then update the table when I finish. So, having set my goals, what would be your suggested approach ? Also I would like to know, apart of the SQLite database file itself, which other files I should pack with my application executable file in order to distribute and install in other machines ? Thanks a lot for any direction on this.

Comment: You don't really need to worry about Sqlite being unidirectional:  Most of the interfaces to back-end Sql Servers are unidirectional, and it is one of the functions of the interface library (like dbExpress) to provide the caching necessary to allow unidirectional sources to be used with Delphi's db-access components.  For Sqlite deployment, you need the Sqlite DLL, usually Sqlite3.Dll, whatever files your db interface library needs (for dbExpress, that is a DLL and a couple of INI files), plus youe Delphi executable.

Comment: Thank you, @MartynA. Normally I program my little apps in Python and I just need import SQLite into my code and everything works fine. I am taking myself into Delphi because it is a bit easier to create GUI than Python and also because I know some Pascal. As per your suggestion, I will try dbExpress and see how it goes. Again, thanks for your time in answering my question. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to worry about SQLite being unidirectional: most of the interfaces to back-end SQL servers are unidirectional, and it is one of the functions of the interface library (like dbExpress, FireDAC and even ADO) to provide the caching necessary to allow unidirectional sources to be used with Delphi's db-access components.

For SQLite deployment, you need [the SQLite DLL, usually `sqlite3.dll`](https://sqlite.org/download.html#win32), whatever files your db interface library needs (for dbExpress, that is a DLL and a couple of INI files, `dbxdrivers.ini` and `dbxconnections.ini`), plus your Delphi executable.